# Why Isn't Google Closure More Popular?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, google-closure

So, Google released this sweet little framework a year or two ago called Closure. There hasn't been much adoption (other than playing w/ the compiler's advanced compile feature ;) and I'm curious as to why.

Is it because of the initial overhead to setup and integrate Closure in to your build? Is the actual js library too verbose/foreign (relative to other js frameworks)? Did the "bad press" it [received](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-closure-how-not-to-write-javascript/) right after launch (re: inefficient techniques and bad practices) leave a bad taste in the mouths of developers? Is Closure more geared towards web-apps than websites (where, obviously, websites are more prevalent)? Or is everyone really just *that* satisfied with jQuery[*](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/javascript_library/all)?

For the record, when I say Closure I mean the whole suite of tools: the compiler, js library, templating system, and linter/inspector. Also, I would love answers tailored more to a site that's in Alexa's top 500 than your average mom and pop shop.

Comment: You might try this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com. It seems more appropriate there. Stack Overflow is for more concrete questions.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles on this, question is now here: [http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105074/why-isnt-google-closure-more-popular](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105074/why-isnt-google-closure-more-popular)